# Create multiple similar pods with different names

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to benchmark my system by creating many pods running the same container. I'm using the following example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cuda-vector-add
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
    - name: cuda-vector-add
      # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.7.11/test/images/nvidia-cuda/Dockerfile
      image: "k8s.gcr.io/cuda-vector-add:v0.1"
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 1 # requesting 1 GPU
```

How can I run this YAML file multiple times such that a new pod with a different name is created?

Comment: you can set the `replicas` property to the number of pods you want. If you want them to have different names just apply then change the name and apply again. also look into [replicaSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating several similar objects to benchmark some component in Kubernetes, I would either sed the resources name from some file/template, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

# make sure my-bench.yaml resource names are set to/based on PLACEHOLDER_NAME
for count in $(seq 1 10)
do
    sed "s|PLACEHOLDER_NAME|bench-$count|" my-bench.yaml | kubectl apply -f-
done
```

This can be useful when you have lots of objects, keeping your script readable.

When I don't have a lot of yaml to write, I would just use cat, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

for count in $(seq 1 10)
do
    cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f-
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: bench-$count
  namespace: my-bench-ns
spec:
...
EOF
done
```

While as suggested by @replicaSets and @karan525: when working with a deployment/replicaset/... you should be able to scale out, adding replicas.

Comment: Thank you for an elegant answer. I primarily want to work with Pods for now. However, by using replicas property in deployments and replicaset is a good option for scaling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replicas in spec. All pods created will have different names but the container in every one of them will be the same

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is running a bare Kubernetes Pod.  This is unusual for a couple of reasons, one of the key ones being that there is only one of it.

In practice you almost always use one of the higher-level objects; most often a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), but occasionally a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) (if you need persistence or a fixed, ordered naming for the Pods) or a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) (for things that need to run once and then exit).

Both Deployments and StatefulSets support `replicas:` which do exactly what you want, run multiple *identical* copies of a Pod.  You'll frequently want this for resiliency if nothing else.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # <-- matches kind:
kind: Deployment    # <-- not Pod
metadata:
  name: cuda-vector-add
spec:
  replicas: 3       # <-- add
  template:
    spec:           # <-- same as your existing Pod spec
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: cuda-vector-add
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/cuda-vector-add:v0.1"
          resources:
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

You can use imperative commands like [`kubectl scale`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#scale) to dynamically change the `replicas:` value.